# What does this syntax means -----> " !! " in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am reading "Discover Meteor" at the moment,
In chapter 7 is has code:

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    // only allow posting if you are logged in
    return !! userId;                        ///// <<==== what does "!!" means?
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beautifully summed up by Tom Ritter as

```
// Maximum Obscurity:
val.enabled = !!userId;

// Partial Obscurity:
val.enabled = (userId != 0) ? true : false;

// And finally, much easier to understand:
val.enabled = (userId != 0);
```

therefore doing casting to a boolean and then doing double negation

Answer (score 1):

! will turn any positive value, true, or existing variable(such as strings and arrays) into a false, and any negative, undefined, null, or false into a true.
!! applies it twice.

In this context it would be returning true if the variable userId exists and is not empty, null, or false.

Answer (score 0):

It just likes you change variable type to boolean

```
!! userId;

// same as

userId ? true:false;
```